# MariaDB / MySQL: STRING DEFAULT ( using other tables and inkrement )

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, concatenation

I'm at my first steps with MariaDB, and I need to implement unique strings as default value in a table.
The string depends on three other tables and if this is not enough to be unique I need to inkremet.

So I want something like this:
`'Table1.Name_Table2.ID_Table3.Dateoffirstuse-5'`

I tried
`Table4.ColumnName CHAR(30) DEFAULT (concat(Table1.Name(Table4.RefTable1),'_', ...))`
but I get error 1064.

Is it possible to use the result of `concat()` as default? And if so, how do I get the right reference if the table is not directly linked? Like Table2 and Table3 in this example, which are connected to Table1, but not to Table4. And, last but not least, how can I add an inkrement to this string?

Comment: [Data Type Default Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html). *Subqueries, parameters, variables, stored functions, and user-defined functions are not permitted.*

Comment: Thank you! As I said, I'm pretty new in mySQL. Is there any way, to realize this kind of unique string somehow?

Comment: In MySQL- no problems. ENGINE = MyISAM, field with described concatenated value set by trigger logic plus autoincremented field, composite PK from this 2 fields. Search MariaDB documentation - I think this is applicable to it too.